# How to force no cache using javascript and basic script loading

Tags: javascript, caching, src

I have a bookmarklet that keeps using cache versions of `http://www.imvu-e.com/products/hpv/download/HPV.js`. I want it to never cache it and always reload it.

This is the hyperlink I use to save the bookmarklet (which users drag to browser toolbar that installs it):

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){
     c = document.createElement(&quot;script&quot;);
     c.type = &quot;text/javascript&quot;;
     c.src = &quot;http://www.imvu-e.com/products/hpv/download/HPV.js&quot;;

     c.onload = c.onreadystatechange = function()                    {
            if ( ! (d = this.readyState) || d == &quot;loaded&quot; || d == &quot;complete&quot;){
                document.documentElement.childNodes[0].removeChild(c);
                version='beta';
            }
     };
     document.documentElement.childNodes[0].appendChild(c);
})();">Run HPV</a>
```

Comment: pretty bad mix of js / html.. use a js framework

Comment: @yes123 It's a bookmarklet, and you're supposed to put a decent chunk of js in the url (because it needs to carry out the loading of your more complex js files)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add a useless querystring to the end of your url:

```
c.src = "http://www.imvu-e.com/products/hpv/download/HPV.js?" + (new Date).getTime();
```

Comment: Had to use `c.src = "http://www.imvu-e.com/products/hpv/download/HPV.js?" + new Date().getTime();`

Comment: @NiCkNewman `Date.now()` maybe faster, but it doesn't work in IE6 ;]

Answer (score 2):

Pure JS solution:

```
<script> 
var scr = document.createElement("script");
scr.src = "http://example.com/cool.js" + "?ts=" + new Date().getTime();
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scr);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's getScript instead of a script tagging and altering the source

```
<script>
   $.getScript("JavascriptFileName.js?timestamp=" + new Date().getTime());
</script>
```

Comment: I'm writing as an SO reviewer because your answer has been flagged for its quality. Please be aware when answering that your answers could be read many times in future. This makes it important to write explanatory notes in them. Would you please take a moment or two to edit your answer with some text that says how and why your answer provides a solution?