# JS + Cache issue in IE7

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have a program whcih loads a number of JS files. It works absolutely fine on all platforms but not on IE7 - Yes IE7. Even if I keep load settings to EVERY TIME I VISIT THE PAGE, even then it loads files from the cache. So to avoid it I added timestamp with JS files and tried to load with dynamic and unique URL every time. It is working fine again on all other browsers but not on IE7. My code is:

```
document.write('<script src="' + Filename + '?dev=' + dateStr + '"\><\/script>');
```

When I check temporary internet files, it truncats the variable part (timestamp **?dev=' + dateStr**) and loads the file with filename only. So when page is refreshed, it picks the file from cache again. Any suggestion please.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, try something like `'#ie' + dateStr` at the end of the URL you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out Noman Solution as well..

the one works for me! is mentioned below

> Loading using File

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.src = 'path/to/file?' + new Date().getMilliseconds();

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

> Loading using Online Repo

With **Jquery**

```
$.getScript("http://repoforjs.com/myjsfile.js");
```

With **JavaScript**

```
var scr = document.createElement("script");
scr.src = "http://repoforjs.com/myjsfile.js" + "?ts=" new Date().getTime();
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].append(scr);
```

For further reference please visit

[Reference 01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399936/how-to-force-no-cache-using-javascript-and-basic-script-loading)

[Reference 02](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/efficientjs.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the following tags

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="+dateStr+" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

I think it should it work.